# Make quiet quieter and loud louder using vst or equalizer apo

Tags: microphone, vst, noise-reduction, loudness

Excuse me for my English and my repeats in advance.

So i need to do the exact opposite of what normalizers do. My mic has extreme spatial sensitivity(condenser mic without 48v) and it catches even a dude coughing outside. I need to get rid of that but not in the simple way(noise gate is disturbing, I do not want noise to kick up every time i click a mouse). I want something like a Contrast in imagery so i can catch both rabbits-getting rid of the noise and getting rid of the background sounds like someone talking in a background or someone cough outside of my house.

I imagine it like db to db spline curve where i can delete quiet sounds from my stream and only my voice without this quiet sounds comes trough. So this is how it is different from noise gate or expander.

Or as i described, like brightness\contrast sliders in imagery to set my voice loudness(-30db for example) and stretch other volumes in both ways from there.

All of this I can maybe describe like "per-frequency" expander, not the whole spectrum at once

Comment: This is very confused. I can only assume you think "normalisers" compress. They don't. What you're looking for is an expander, which is the 'opposite' of a compressor. It's like a gate but more flexible. "Dynamic mic effect" is also not true - more or less sensitivity is not the issue. I can also only guess that 'extreme spacial sensitivity' is an omni-directional mic. You cannot do anything about that except use a cardioid instead.

Comment: it is cardioid, my mic is just pointed to the window and no, expander is not what i'm looking for, it acts just like a gate but i need to fully eliminate this quiet sounds. I can maybe describe it like "per-frequency" expander, not the whole spectrum at once.
About normalizers - i did not find ones in which you can "denormalize" the sound. they always restrict you only to only compression. If you have any that do not do that, then please tell me

Comment: Normalisation contains no compression behaviour at all. It is a single 'volume control' affecting the entire track, based on a loudest point. Noise reduction techniques are varied, but involve analysis of what is 'signal' & what is 'background'. So far, best start point would be… don't point your mic where the background is significant. Move somewhere it isn't. There's no real substitute for mic placement. For pseudo-intelligent noise reduction, see [iZotope RX](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/rx.html)

Answer (score 1):

The situation you are describing is where I would use a noise gate. When there is talk going on, the gate opens. When there is no talk going on, the noise gate closes and there will be silence.

This is only possible when there is a difference in volume between the sound you want to keep and ambient noise. If the ambient noise is stronger than the voice a simple noise gate will not work.

A noise gate will have several different parameters that can be tweaked to get the best result. Most important is the treshold control -- used to set the level where the gate will open. If the gate opens on mouse clickings you need to increase the treshold level.

The other parameters of the noise gate are used to fine tune the output in order to make it sound as good as possible to the ears. This includes setting attack, hold and reduction.

Sometimes it is possible to get better results by side-chaining the noise gate. In this case I would take the signal through a bandpass filter set to fit my voice. The bandpass signal is then used to open the noise gate. Spurios other sounds most often will not open the gate.

Sometimes it makes the result better when adding a small bit of "ambience" or noise to the signal after the noise gate as the feeling when the gate closes can be sort of like the "air is sucked out".

An alternative tool to use sometimes is called expander.